# Using the output from Checklist-Model in Angular application

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

I am using the Checklist-Model directive in my application and it is returning a value like below:

```
{"sets":[{"title":"342","objectId":"1j9p9R1xzM"},{"title":"bkjkjb","objectId":"esHE2WIEkN"}]}
```

My question is how can I use this output. I tried to pass it into JSON.parse, but this seems to be causing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused about the syntax for getting the input.  The example from the model needs to be set like follows:

```
selectedSets.sets[0]
```

not

```
selectedSets[0]
```

Comment: What did you specify in your code as the checlist-model? You shouldn't need any eval or JSON,parse to use the checlist-model.